# Hierarchical "Select GameObject" Dialog or names with prefixes?

Tags: unity

I am attempting to connect a series of teleporters with entrances inside a single scene. Once the player touches a teleporter he is moved to another place. I am doing this by simply connecting two game objects as shown in the following screenshot. The particle system in the center of the upper side is used as teleporter, the red line indicates the game object where the player will be transported to.

[image: A simple scene showing the connection of a teleporter to an entrance]

Sadly, this results in an utter mess when attempting to select a new entrance the teleporter should link to. There is no way to guess which entrance corresponds to which side and dice:

[image]

**So the tl;dr of my problem would be this: The name of the object that should be selected is meaningless when isolated. It's the path to the object (or in other terms: the name of some parent) that is relevant.**

I would see three possibilities to solve this, but sadly I haven't gotten around to find out how to do any of them.

1. Switch the "Select GameObject" Dialog to use the same hierarchical view as used in the scene viewer. Is there a hidden option somewhere in Unity that I overlooked?
2. Somehow prefix the names of my entrances programatically. Is there a way to include the path to a certain game object in its name?
3. My whole approach is backwards and I am doing something in a not Unity friendly way. But what would be the "correct" way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should share your teleportation code here as well

Comment: I don't see how the teleportation code would be useful here. This question (as the title states) is not about teleportation. The code itself has quite a few unique tidbits regarding the need to switch gravity, so I wouldn't think it would be helpful to anyone else.

Comment: Would changing the way the script works to working with handles be an option? That would remove the need to manage countless teleporter -> destination objects and will allow you to manage the destinations on the teleporter itself (you could also add in Gizmos to better display the link between them)

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Unity. What do you mean with "handle"?

Comment: [Handles](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.html) [Gizmos](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.html) and you can use the [position handle](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.PositionHandle.html) to achieve what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You can attach custom script to any gameobject you want to use as destination call it for example TeleportDestination.

In your entry teleport script you can use public property type TeleportDestination, now unity will pops you only objects with TeleportDestination and not all gameobjects.

Note: TeleportDestination needs to be MonoBehaviour.
Note 2: you can create a method in TeleportDestination for teleporting and use it with more entry types later on with same teleporting logic.

Ps: i wrote this answer on mobile. I would go deeper otherwise, sorry. Hope it helps

Comment: This would at least filter down the "Select GameObject" Dialog to nothing but entries called "Entrance". But it doesn't really solve the problem that the individual name is not meaningful, only the path to it.

Comment: you can drag that gameobject directly from hierarchy or you can use Vexes VFW https://github.com/vexe/VFW, for example use RequiredFromChildren with TeleportDestination and select its parent with meaningful name